# What is the time complexity of below DP code for generating all balanced parentheses?

Tags: java, algorithm, dynamic-programming

```
public List<String> generateParenthesis(int n) {
    if (n < 1) {
        return Arrays.asList("");
    } else if (n == 1) {
        return Arrays.asList("()");
    } else {
        Set<String> set = new HashSet<>(n * 2);
        for (String s : generateParenthesis(n - 1)) {
            char[] ca = s.toCharArray();
            int len = s.length();
            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                set.add(String.copyValueOf(ca, 0, i) + "()"
                        + String.copyValueOf(ca, i, len - i));
            }
        }
        return new ArrayList<String>(set);
    }
}
```

I found the above code online from an old post https://rekinyz.wordpress.com/2015/02/13/generate-parentheses/. It is a bottom-up dynamic programming approach for generating all valid parentheses which would work. But I am not sure how to explain the worst time complexity of this solution. Can  someone plz tell what is the time complexity of this code & why it is so? Original article doesn't  have anything about the time complexity.

Comment: This is not dynamic programming. There is no memoization. Calculating the time complexity is quite complex here. It involves Catalan numbers. Look into that.

Comment: No memoization, but it uses tabulation, right @trincot? It builds the solution in a bottom-up manner. Previous step result is stored & used to calculate the current step result.

Comment: Yes, it uses tabulation, although still in a top-down manner, as *n* set objects are created before getting to the base case.

Comment: I still think it is bottom-up manner. Line "for (String s : generateParenthesis(n - 1)) {"  will first satisfy the base case. Then it will incrementally build the result case using tabulation.

Comment: Think of how it would be with top-down. Surely you also then need the base cases before you can increment the result. That is not what distinguishes bottom up from top down.